# Summing up horizontally with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data represented as below:

```
ENO    A    B   C   D   
1001    0   0   1.2 0   
1001    1.9 0   0   2.2 
1002    0   0   0   0   
1002    0   0   6.6 0   
1002    0   0   3   0   
1003    0   0   0   0   
1003    0   0   0   1   
1004    0   2   0   0   
1004    0   3   0   0   
1004    0   0   0   0   
1004    0   0   2   0
```

I'm trying to sum up columns A, B, C and D horizontally like below:

```
ENO     A   B   C   D           ENO       SUM_T
1001    0   0   1.2 0          1001        5.3
1001    1.9 0   0   2.2        
1002    0   0   0   0          1002        9.6
1002    0   0   6.6 0   
1002    0   0   3   0   
1003    0   0   0   0          1003        1
1003    0   0   0   1   
1004    0   2   0   0          1004        7
1004    0   3   0   0   
1004    0   0   0   0   
1004    0   0   2   0
```

How do I specify the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

[image]

In **F1** enter:

```
=SUM(B1:E1)
```

and copy down.  In **G1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **G2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)
```

and copy down.  In **H1** enter:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,G1,F:F)
```

In **H2** enter:

```
=IF(G2="","",SUMIF(A:A,G2,F:F))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: I prefer this method in this instance; the helper column is very clean as it follows the format of the other data, and it allows for a simple SUMIF function which is easier for less advanced Excel users to read on review.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more eloquent way to accomplish this, but pictured here is how I would do it. This uses four SUMIF functions, one for each column, added together to calculate the total. For the first 'ENO' value 1001, the function looks in the first column (marked 'A') and sums any match to the value 1001. Then we do this for the second column (marked 'B') and so forth. This is repeated for each value that you want a sum total for.

Formula used for the first 'ENO' value 1001:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,F2,B:B)+SUMIF(A:A,F2,C:C)+SUMIF(A:A,F2,D:D)+SUMIF(A:A,F2,E:E)
```

This formula would be repeated for each 'ENO' value, where cell 'F2' contains the search value.

[image]

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on the answer or how the formulas were created. :)

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdxpm.png)

**Note**: Thank you Jeeped for inserting the image

Comment: I've posted your image; maybe you could edit to include text based samples of your formula(s)? Put 4 spaces at the beginning of the line to force 'Code Mode'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) to supply a [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) for multiple columns.

[image: sumproduct_dynamic_ranges]

The formulas in F2:G2 are:

```
=IF(A2<>A1, A2, "")
=IF(F2="", "", SUMPRODUCT(B$2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))*(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))=F2)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

The SUMPRODUCT function does not like full column column references, preferring to calculate every row whether there is anything populating the cell or not. This adaptation restricts the scope of the ranges to only exactly what is required.