# Excel Transpose and Link Simultanously

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to link on cell to another so that its content changes to match the source cell.

I know how to transpose a row into a column.

Is there any way to transpose a row into a column with links that dynamically adjust to match their source?

Answer (score 0):

Try locking your cell references before transposing them.  Turn your formula from:

```
=B2
```

to

```
=$B$2
```

If you do not add the $ to the row and column part of the cell address, the address will change during the transpose operation.

In my example, I filled the cells A1 to E1 with their a1 to e1 to match their cell address.  In the row below, I put `=$A$1` in A2 and so on to `=$E$1` in E2.  You will notice the formula for E2 in the formula bar from this screen shot:

[image]

I then selected the cell for the top of my transposed column (in my case C4) and right clicked and selected paste special: (note there is a short paste transpose, but I cold not get the right click menu to screen shot)

[image]

And here we see the transposed column with the formula in C4 is `=$A$1` and the formula in C8 is `=$E$1`

[image]

Comment: @SanBackups  Please sea edit with screen shots.  if this is not working for you please provide some example of what you are trying to do.  Say a three rows or 3 columns that you are trying to transpose.  you shold show the formula in each of the source cells and show what you are expecting as a final result.

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873280/summing-up-horizontally-with-condition/33873699#33873699) as a potential example on how to provided example data.