# For dates with missing data, take average of values from closest dates

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have sporadically collected data for stream nitrogen levels. For dates where nitrogen levels are not available, I'm hoping I can use an Excel formula that will estimate the value by calculating the average of nitrogen levels from the two closest dates.Note that nitrogen is not correlated with flow (or other water quality parameters) and there is no trend so I can't use a regression equation to estimate values.

Below is an example of what the table looks like for columns A, B, and C, and rows 1 (header) to 7. Column B contains the real data (note that I inserted 'no value' for illustrative purposes). Column C is what I would like to have calculated. Because I have thousands of rows of data, manually entering each of these formulas is not an option.

Date_______Actual Value______Desired Calculation

1/1/2012_______0.15__________=B2

1/2/2012_____[no value]_______=AVERAGE(B2,B5)

1/3/2012_____[no value]_______=AVERAGE(B2,B5)

1/4/2012_______0.17__________=B5

1/5/2012_____[no value]_______=AVERAGE(B5,B7)

1/6/2012_______0.23__________=B7

Comment: Please show your formula/code.

Comment: This post is pretty close to what I need, but I'm hoping it can be a drag down formula since I have thousands of rows of data.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762340/fill-non-contiguous-blank-cells-with-the-value-from-the-cell-above-the-first-bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B1<>"",B1,VLOOKUP(MAX($A$1:$A$4),$A$1:$B$4,2,0))
```

Misread the question the first time.

Test to see if B1 is equal to "" or not.  If it is empty then perform the VLOOKUP searching for the max value of column A (most recent date), and then use the value for the adjacent column (2).

This will not cover the case where the most recent Date has no value in column B.  I will return "" in that case.

### TREND Option

Based on your comments and the use of some helper cells you could do the following.  Make a small table off to the right somewhere of just your known dates and your known values from B.  We can populate this table using the following formulas.  Let arbitrarily put this table in columns F and G.

in F2 use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1564,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$1564)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($B$2:$B$1564<>""),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")
```

This will pull the dates in order that they appear with values in B that are not "".  Then in G2 put the following formula in which will pull the associated value from B

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$1564,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$1564)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($B$2:$B$1564<>""),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")
```

Both those formulas are currently set up to work with a header row and data starting in row 2.

once we have the helper table set up, you can set up a TREND function, which is a line of best fit through all your known points.  You can pick the point on this line for dates with no value in B.  In C2 you would add:

=IF(B2="",TREND($G$2:$G$3,$F$2:$F$3,A2),B2)

you would copy this formula down.  It checks to see if B is blank.  If it is then it pulls a value for B from the trend line.  If it is not blank, then it will use the value in B.

## AVERAGE Option

Again using the helper table in the same spot.  This one gets a little uglier.  In C2 place the following and copy down

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2,IF($A2<$F$2,$G$2,IF($A2>$F$3,$G$3,(INDEX($G$2:$G$3,IFERROR(MATCH($A2,$F$2:$F$3,1),1))+INDEX($G$2:$G$3,IFERROR(MATCH($A2,$F$2:$F$3,1)+1,2)))/2)))
```

The first thing it does is check for a blank value in B.  If there is no blank then it uses the value in B2.  If there is no value in B2 it then proceeds to check the date of the blank against the first date in your helper table.  If it is less than that first value, it uses the first value of B since there is nothing to average it with.  I then proceeds to do the same to see if the date exceeds the last value in the table. (this is currently hard coded).  If it exceeds the last date in the table it uses the last value for B.  the last option for the date is for it to be in the table.  It take the average between the date prior to the date and question and the next date with a value.

Optional version where you dont have to hard code the last values of helper table, but you still need to hard code the range of the helper table to meet your needs.

```
=IF(B3<>"",B3,IF($A3<$F$2,$G$2,IF($A3>MAX($F$2:$F$3),VLOOKUP(MAX($F$2:$F$3),$F$2:$G$3,2,0),(INDEX($G$2:$G$3,IFERROR(MATCH($A3,$F$2:$F$3,1),1))+INDEX($G$2:$G$3,IFERROR(MATCH($A3,$F$2:$F$3,1)+1,2)))/2)))
```

## TREND Between only two points

So I adjusted the formula a bit on this one.  Its kind of a mix of the trend and previous options listed above.  I also made it automatically selecting the end values of your table, so now you just have to copy your table down as far as you need.  Its also works on the premise that only your data value in B are present, no numbers below your last row.

```
=IF($A2<$F$2,$G$2,IF($A2>=MAX(OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT(B:B),1)),VLOOKUP(MAX(OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT(B:B),1)),OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT(B:B),2),2,0),TREND(OFFSET($F$2,IFERROR(MATCH($A2,OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT(B:B),1),1),0)-1,1,2,1),OFFSET($F$2,IFERROR(MATCH($A2,OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT(B:B),1),1)-1,0),0,2,1),$A2)))
```

So basically TREND function is a line of best fit through known points.  if your know points do not all sit in a straight line it figures out what straight line passes near them minimizing the distance they are from the line.  If we limit the points it using to make its line to only 2 points, then the line has to pass through those two points.  Remember, the helper table is a list of all known points.

So basically what the formula doing is checking to see if the date is less than or equal to the first known point on the helper table.  If it is, use the value from the first known point in the table.  If its not, check to see if the date is greater than the last date in the table, if it is lookup the last known date in the table and return the corresponding table.  If neither of these cases is true then the date must be in the table.  That means we can get two points from the table and their corresponding values to use in the trend function.  We feed the TREND function a an array of 2 known X and 2 Know Y values, and then supply it with an X value we are interested in.  In this case X would be the dates, and Y would be the values in the second column.

## Revised Helper table

In F2 use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1))-ROW($A$2)+1)/(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1)<>""),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")
```

and G2 use this formula:

```
=IF(F2="","",INDEX(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1),MATCH(F2,OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1),0)))
```

and if you want to verify how far down you want to copy your helper table, you can put this in lets say I3:

```
=COUNT(B:B)+1
```

Now these update that are using the count(A:A) or B:B  require that no other numbers be above or below your data in the A or B column.

### UPDATED Average

I also tweaked the average formula to give this option as well.

```
=IF($B2<>"",$B2,IF($A2<=$F$2,$G$2,IF($A2>=MAX(OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT($B:$B),1)),VLOOKUP(MAX(OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT($B:$B),1)),OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT($B:$B),2),2,0),AVERAGE(OFFSET($F$2,IFERROR(MATCH($A2,OFFSET($F$2,0,0,COUNT($B:$B),1),1),0)-1,1,2,1)))))
```

Example results (note rows 14-69 have been hidden so you can see what is happening around row 75.

[image: Example results]

Comment: The most recent date is the one with the largest number, unless you start going into future dates.  I think by most recent you mean the date closest to  the date with the missing value.

Comment: Ooops- yes I mean the closest date. Taking the average between the closest dates would also be helpful.

Comment: not that it really matters, but you have changed the dates just now from what you gave in your example earlier.  Sometime instead of describing a table with just words, it can be helpful to include a snipet of [example data similar to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873280/summing-up-horizontally-with-condition/).  You have to manually format it unfortunately as you cannot cut an paste a table last time I checked.  leave a blank row from your last paragraph and start each line with 4 spaces should get you started.

Comment: does you column of dates increase by 1 day for each row?  would it be safe to assume that if you wre graphing the points with B being the Y value and your dates being the X value that It would be a straight line inbetween?  If so that can be an interpolation.  might use something like trend. If 1/1/2012 to 1/8/2012 are all blank, what number do you want to see used for all of them? 0.21?  Will the number in b when present always be larger than the previous value in b that is present?

Comment: Shoot- turns out the Average Option only gets me part of the way there. I have thousands of dates in total, but only about 75 dates of real, known data. Therefore, the formula doesn't work after row 75...

Comment: yeah just saw you update, and then I had more data points to work with bare with me

Comment: OK, make sure you copy the formulas in helper table downward until it only displays blanks.  Then make sure you change the reference of F2:F3 and F2:G3 and G2:G3 so that the last row is the same as the last row of your helper table.

Comment: I actually wasn't able to get the helper table formula to work so I had hard copied the actual values into columns F and G. But if I need that formula, here is what I'm using (Instead of A2:A45 I used A2:A1564 (same for B). Any thoughts on why it's just producing the "" or Name? error (if I remove IFERROR from the formula: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1564,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$1564)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($B$2:$B$1564<>""),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")

Comment: The formulas are supposed to make the helper table automatic in the sense of no typos or missed dates.  What is the last row of your actual data and are you using a header row in your actual data.  I will try and adjust formulas if possible...Do  you know how to post a screen shot?  Just thinking a screen shot of what is happening around row 75 might be helpful along with the helper table.

Comment: In windows in order to take a screen shot, make excel your active window.  make sure the information you want to show is on it.  press and hold alt and then the print screen button.  Then got to a site like [imgur](http://imgur.com/).  In the upper left part of their site is a blue button to upload.  click on it and then press control V.  Then select the upload button.  You can then edit your image if you which to crop it to the information you want.  when you are ready to post it here, copy the direct link address on the right of the imgur site. Edit your Q here and insert phot using the link

Comment: The reason the trend option MAY be better than the average, is the closer to the date where you do have a number you may want a value that is closer to that number.  As you mover further from the previous known number and closer to the next known number, you may want your value closer to that next known number.

Comment: If you remove the IFERROR part of the formula you will see errors towards the bottom when it can no longer find dates in your table.  And sorry I did not see that you had edit your last comment until just now.  If you pull out the IFERROR form the fomula you mentioned, you also need to pull off the ,"") from the other end.  The IFERROR is producing "" returns after the formula can no longer find dates with values beside it.

Comment: Your 'Trend between two points' will definitely do and actually gets me better data than the average as you said. That is one heck of a formula. Would you mind describing briefly exactly what it does? I still wasn't able to get the revised helper table formula to work. If I better understood what it was doing I could try to tweak it but I'm a little lost on it. Thanks for sticking with this problem and helping me out.

Comment: That helper table is actually really key to all of this, so let make sure its working.  Try to break it down one step at a time.  What formula are you using currently in your F2.  If it is giving an error, what is the error.

Comment: In F2 the formula is: =IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1))-ROW($A$2)+1)/(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1)<>""),ROWS(B$2:B2))),""). If I remove the IFERROR part, the error I get is #Name?. In G2 I have the following formula: =IF(F2="","",INDEX(OFFSET($A$2,0,1,COUNT(A:A),1),MATCH(F2,OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT(A:A),1),0)))

Comment: Why are you removing the IFERROR?

Comment: tell me if you have the aggregate function available to you in your version of excel? and that raises a better question, what version of excel are you running?

Comment: Alternate way to build the helper table if you dont have the aggregate function available to you.  copy you column A and B to another part of the sheet, or another worksheet.  Select the entier new table (first and second column from top row to bottom row.  Then do a sort on the list, but sort by the second column.  This should put all the spaces at the bottom.  Delete all the dates with spaces.  resort the table based on date this time.  You now have a helper table to use in F2.

Comment: That's the problem. I have Excel 2010 and it doesn't recognize the AGGREGATE function. But when IT upgrades my system (hopefully someday soon)- I'll definitely want to start using that function. For now I'll just keep a hard entered helper table. Thank you again @Forward Ed.

Comment: did you get it working past row 75? or better yet, with your hardcoded helper table, did the other formulas work for you in terms of filling in column C down to row 1564?

Comment: The formula works beautifully all the way down. One thing I'm curious about- do the date and value column need to be next to each other? I noticed that will I had a column of flow data between my date and nitrogen value columns, the formula started not working.

Comment: Never mind about the between dates issue. I figured out what was happening. I was referencing the wrong column in one of the parts of the formula. Thanks again.

Comment: I have been using your formula for Trend Between Only Two Points. Randomly, after a certain number of dates, the formula seems to get 'stuck' for some reason and only shows the most recent value rather than the trend between the two points. I can't figure out what is going on. Any thoughts? Can I attach the spreadsheet here? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry had my head out of this question too long now, and forgot what I was doing.  I see I was using the offset formula in it, and I have since learned that it is best to avoid that formula when dealing with large amounts of data or large amounts of calculations in a spreadsheet as it is a volatile function.  I would recommend you post as a new question describing what is happening, give a point where data is going ary, show the formulas you are using as what have your tried so far, and link to this question and state you are asking a follow up question.  You may even get other ways to do this

Comment: Thanks @Forward Ed- I will repost.